# typesafe config empty value

Tags: scala, playframework, typesafe-config

Is there any way to load .conf file that have empty value for properties ?

i.e

```
prop1 = 
prop2 =
```

if not is there any good practice how to handle that?

the reason why i am using that is because i dont want to read file.
i want to write to a properties file  i.e

```
def replaceProperties(sourceFile:String,map:Map[String,String])={
    import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
    import java.io.File
    val config = ConfigLoader(Some(new File(sourceFile)))
    val properties = ConfigValueFactory.fromMap(map)
    val merged = properties.withFallback(config)
    //write $merged to a file

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, do you want read or do you want to write those empty values? Do you want them to be empty (empty strings) or None/null values? Is there an error when readin/writing the values?

Comment: i want to write properties to this file(But there is an option that not all keys on this file, which means i need to keep the empy keys).